# How to pass variable in db.all in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I've hit a problem. I would like to know if there is a way to pass the variable req into the db.all function ?

```
app.get('/sendMail', (req, res) => {
    var sql="SELECT email FROM dentists WHERE id="+req.param('id');
    db.all(sql,function(err,rows){
        if (err) 
            res.render('reponse', { err:err});
        else
            mailOptions={
                from: 'toothFairy.noreply@gmail.com',
                to: rows[0].email,
                subject: 'New message from '+req.param('firstname')+' '+req/param('lastname'),
                text: req.param('message')
            };
    });
    res.render('home');
})
```

Comment: What is `db.all`? What library is `db`?

Comment: db is the variable to connect to the sqlite database and .all is to execute the request sql.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is there an error? What do you need to pass?

Comment: you have a typo: `req/param('lastname')` should be `req.param('lastname')`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can access as `db.all` is inside that callback no need to pass as parameter you can directly access

```
app.get('/sendMail', (req, res) => {
        var sql="SELECT email FROM dentists WHERE id="+req.param('id');
        db.all(sql,function(err,rows){
            if (err) 
                res.render('reponse', { err:err});
            else
                mailOptions={
                    from: 'toothFairy.noreply@gmail.com',
                    to: rows[0].email,
                    subject: 'New message from '+req.param('firstname')+' '+req.param('lastname'),
                    text: req.param('message')
                };
        });
        res.render('home');
    })
```